# Comparison of friendly analysis texts: Abbot, Bryant, Strichartz, Schramm, Kumar&Kumaresan

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am looking for a "friendly, for dummies, easy as possible" first book intro to real analysis that is suitable for self study for people not having taken a course in proof writing.

I have searched around a lot, and I have found that the above mentioned books seems to fit my wanted type of book.

However, the books are always compared to more difficult books (e.g. Rudin, Apostol), and they are not compared to each other.

Hence, I would be very interested in hearing about the differences between the mentioned books, so if anybody has read more than one of the mentioned books, please let me know!